# Apply Condition in DidselectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView which has different types of files and folders in it, Right i have set a method that passes to another view controller once clicked on a row. What i need is that once a row is clicked on it checks what kind of a file is in the row and then connects to different uiviewcontrollers on the basis of that.

My UiTableView has two items in each cell 
A Cell Label & Cell Detail Text Label

The DetailTextLabel holds the Subject type 
i.e. Folder (For Folders) & File (For Files like jpeg. , png., etc.)

I want to use the if condition in the didselectrowatindexpath to distinguish between file and folder

Comment: Yes, just write that if condition you mentioned, and use `performSegueWithIdentifier`, `pushViewController`, etc. for the desired `UIViewController` that will show up based on the condition (different file kind).

Comment: can you put some code for cellforrowatindexpath method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by checking value of `cell.detailTextLabel.text` like following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *str = cell.detailTextLabel.text;

    if ([str isEqualToString:@"Folder"])
    {
        // Open Folder Detail View. For Example:
        FolderViewController* objVC = [[FolderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FolderViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objVC animated:YES];
    }
    else if ([str isEqualToString:@"File"])
    {
        // Open File Detail View. For Example:
        FileViewController* objVC = [[FileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FileViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objVC animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: And it is still impossible to tag you

Comment: FolderViewController* objVC = [[FolderViewController alloc] . every time you pushView, it alloc memory.how it will get released automatically?

Answer (score 0):

in .h file

```
    #import "FolderViewController.h"
    #import "FileViewController.h"

    @interface mainViewController : UIViewController {
            FolderViewController *folderViewObj;
            FileViewController *fileViewObj;
    }
```

in .m file

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            folderViewObj = [[FolderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FolderViewController" bundle:nil];
            fileViewObj = [[FileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FileViewController" bundle:nil];
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            UITableViewCell * cell = [tblObj cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSString *lblText = cell.DetailTextLabel.text;

            if ([lblText isEqualToString:@"Folder"])  {
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:folderViewObj animated:YES];
            }
            else if ([lblText isEqualToString:@"File"])
            {
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fileViewObj animated:YES];
            }
    }

    -(void) dealloc {
            [folderViewObj release];
            [fileViewObj release];
            [super dealloc];
    }
```

using this way, object of FolderViewController and FileViewController is created only once not all time when user can select the row of uitableview.